# python dictionary for incremental values

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to perform the following:
Given a total number of observations (in this case the variable 'total_models'), I would like to parse this for parallel processing by a given number of python sessions ('sessions' variable and 'by' variable).  I figure it best to perform this task using a dictionary.

The desired results should can be found in the 'obs_dict' object.  For any given input to 'total_models', 'sessions' and 'by'.  Can you assist in creating the desired output in a dictionary object?  If possible, I would like to see the answer using some sort of list or dictionary comprehension.

```
total_models=1000000
sessions=4
by=int(total_models/sessions)

### Desired Output.
obs_dict={1:'0:250000',2:'250001:500000',3:'500001:750000',4:'750001:1000000'}
```

Comment: you want 0:250000 or 1:250000 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
obs = {i+1: str(i*by+1)+':'+str((i+1)*by) for i in range(sessions)}
```

## Edited, Kyle:

For the odd models it would seem wrapping a ceil the division will ensure we we do not go over the 'total_models'

```
total_models=1000326
sessions=5
by=math.ceil(total_models/sessions)
obs = {i+1: str(i*by+1)+':'+str(min((i+1)*by,total_models)) for i in range(sessions)}
```

Comment: Vj, I appreciate this line...  So, essentially I can load the dictionary by using list comprehension.  "str(i*by+1)+':'+str((i+1)*by) for i in range(sessions)"  Generates my list and "i+1: wrapped in brackets loads the list to a dictionary.  Again, greatly appreciated!